# C# random number generator with limit for a single number

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want to generate `random` number between lets say 1 to 100. Any number between 1 to 100 can have max limit of 3.

For example if number 2 is generated 3 times, then it should not return number 2, because it is already generated 3 times. Here max limit for any number between 1 to 100 is 3, but any number can be generated less than 3 times.

How do I achieve this without keeping track of each and every number between 1 to 100? Max limit and number range can change.

**Edit:**
Based on answers provide by Zoran Horvat and Alexei Levenkov, It would be difficult to generate random number with occurrence limit without keeping track of numbers and it involves complex solution. I tired to write my own solution using dictionary as follow.

```
//for storing output
        List<int> output = new List<int>();
        //to keep track of numbers
        Dictionary<int, int> numberTrack = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        Random ran = new Random();
        //define max limit and range of numbers
        int maxLimit = 2, min = 1, max = 100 ;
        int no, count;
        //this for loop must run for any number less than max*maxLimit otherwise it will last for long time(may be forever). 
        for (int i = 0; i < max*maxLimit; i++)
        {
            //get random number.
            no = ran.Next(min, max+1);
            //check if random number exists in dictionary
            if (numberTrack.TryGetValue(no, out count))
            {
                //if exists than check for it occurrences 
                if (count >= maxLimit)
                {
                    //if occurrence is greater than maxLimit continue for next number.
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    //else add number to output and update its occurrence count
                    numberTrack[no] += 1;
                    output.Add(no);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //if random number does not exists in the dictionary than add it 
                //with occurrence of 1 and also add it to the ouptput.
                numberTrack.Add(no, 1);
                output.Add(no);
            }
        }
```

But Sergey Berezovskiy's and René Vogt's solution completes the task in few lines of code. I really appreciate all the help I get from this community.

Comment: To my understanding, this is impossible without tracking of previously generated numbers.

Comment: Store counts of numbers you’ve generated in the past in a `Dictionary<int, int>`?

Comment: @Codor Think again. When solving engineering problems, start from the requirements and then construct solution...

Comment: @ZoranHorvat Thanks for the hint. Do you mean something like the answer by Sergey Berezovskiy?

Comment: No, that is tracking numbers. I'm still thinking but with no solution yet.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is a solution without keeping track of each an every number. I have solution in mind for this problem which keep tracks of each and every number using dictionary. I will implement that now.

Comment: I've added the algorithm tag because I'm hoping you don't expect people to write the code for you...

Comment: I have given outlines of complete solutions below, along with analysis of required effort. Conclusion is that it is *possible* to implement solution according to exact requirements, but it is probably better to reconsider requirements and make them less rigid.

Answer (score 6):

1. Generate 3 * 1..100 numbers
2. Shuffle them
3. Iterate shuffled collection

Sample:

```
var random = new Random();
var maxRepetitionsCount = 3;
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1,100)
       .SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Repeat(i, maxRepetitionsCount))
       .OrderBy(i => random.Next())
       .ToList();
```

NOTE: There is no option to keep tracking on occurrences count without tracking occurrences count. It's like *"I want to do X without doing X"*

Comment: This solution remembers all numbers, and requirement was *not* to keep track of them.

Comment: @ZoranHorvat it's the closest solution according to any PRNG math model.

Comment: I think you can actually drop requirement to keep whole shuffled sequence and re-create it on every request (posted as answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42280195/477420). Also from practical point of view keeping numbers is cheapest approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a linq query that generates those numbers:

```
private Random random = new Random();
public IEnumerable<int> RandomNumbers(int limit, int maxOccurence)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, limit)
                     .SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Repeat(i, maxOccurence))
                     .OrderBy(i => random.Next());
}
```

---

This creates a sequence of numbers from 1 to `limit`, then repeats each number `maxOccurence` times and then orders the result by (pseudo-)random numbers. The `random` should be instantiated only once to avoid repeating the same pseudo-random sequences.

---

But note that this will be slow at least for the first numbers as it has to start sorting the whole sequence (which in your example will be 300 numbers, so performance would not yet be a problem).

Comment: This is basically the answer by Sergey Berezovskiy formulated with Linq.

Comment: GUIDs are not random numbers.  They're unique, not random.

Comment: @Codor what's your point? While Sergey was writing his three good points I was writing my query.

Comment: @Servy right, I changed it now to use the `Random` class to avoid a discussion about how good guids are as "random" numbers (because I simply can't judge that now).

Answer (score 1):

Non-practical approaches with keeping just 2 "values".

Since restriction "max 3 times each number in range 1-100" essentially asks for shuffling of 3 set of numbers 1-100 we can represent whole task as picking random permutation first and remembering its position in some order of permutations (e.g. [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order)) and than for each of 300 requests for random number pick next element in that permutation (restoring permutation first).

Note that cost of storing "value" that represent permutation number would be quite insane and likely higher than just storing whole sequence to start with. Restoring permutation by its position would be even less practical.

---

More plausible version would be to replay shuffling for each request assuming you use repeatable random number generator (like on in .Net). This way you just need to store seed for random number generator and index of last "random" number in shuffled collection (increments on each request). You'd still have to allocate array for shuffling but no need to keep it around between calls. Complexity would be quite reasonable as shuffling requires just O(n), so overall to generate all numbers you need O(n) temporary storage per call + 2 fixed size values for PRNG seed and index, and O(n^2) time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the principal outline of the solution. Implementation would not be trivial, and in some cases not even possible.

**Prerequisites**

- Given range 1..M from which numbers are taken.
- Given K as the maximum number of repetitions of any number in the output sequence.
- Given L as length of the sequence that has to be generated.

**Exact Solution**

1. Construct perfect hash function for the range of numbers 1..N, where
   N >= M and hash function produces uniform distribution. One possibility is to apply linear congruent generator, just like common pseudorandom number generators do.
2. Construct an algorithm which splits L into additive components l1 + l2 + ... + lK = L. This algorithm must randomly pick one set of components from a uniform distribution of all possible sets.
3. For numbers 1, 2, 3... map each number to a random number using the perfect hash from first point.
4. Repeat step 3 for l1, l2, ..., lK, which will result in total of L pseudorandom numbers generated.

Bottom line is that generating a pseudorandom sequence within given constraints is extremely complicated. This algorithm would make sense only if N is large and remembering previously generated numbers is prohibitive.

**Approximate Solution**

If it is still important to avoid numbers from repeating, and it is impossible to remember all the previous numbers because their range or total number is great, you can opt for an approximate solution.

For example, you can keep record of some number of values generated and ensure that new value is not present in that subsequence. You can calculate length of the subsequence from M and K in such way that *probability* that any number from sequence 1..M appears more than K times is lower than the greatest acceptable value. Like ensuring that probability that any number appears more than K times is not greater than 10%, or 1%, or so.

Again, implementing this algorithm would be very hard and it pays off only if numbers N and K are such that run-time cost of other solutions is prohibitive.